# Security of ring-lwe sample? can we do it simpler?

Tags: ring-lwe

Assuming

- a secret key $s\in \mathbb{Z}_2[X]/\langle X^n+1\rangle$,
- a plaintext $m\in \mathbb{Z}_2[X]/\langle X^n+1\rangle$,
- $e,e'$ are sampled from B-bounded Discrete Gaussian Distribution over $\mathbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^n+1 \rangle $ with reasonable standard deviation for security.
- $a$  (a part of public key) is a random element sampled unformly at random  from  $\mathbb{Z}_q[X]/\langle X^n+1\rangle$ (q >> 2),
- $b=[-a \cdot s-e]_q$ (a part of public key)
- $u$ is an element over $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/\langle X^n+1\rangle$ (with small coefficient).

Then, is the following RLWE sample secure?

$([u \cdot b + 2 \cdot e' + m]_q,  [u \cdot a]_q)$

Comment: In other word, can we recover $m$ from the RLWE sample without knowing the secret key?